# Save unequal output to a csv or txt file

Tags: r, list, csv

I want to save the following output I get in the R console into a csv or txt file.

```
Discordancy measures (critical value 3.00)
0.17 3.40 1.38 0.90 1.62 0.13 0.15 1.69 0.34 0.39 0.36 0.68 0.39
0.54 0.70 0.70 0.79 2.08 1.14 1.23 0.60 2.00 1.81 0.77 0.35 0.15
1.55 0.78 2.87 0.34 

Heterogeneity measures (based on 100 simulations)
30.86 14.23 3.75 
Goodness-of-fit measures (based on 100 simulations)
glo    gev    gno    pe3    gpa 
-3.72 -12.81 -19.80 -32.06 -37.66
```

This is the outcome I get when I run the following

```
Heter<-regtst(regsamlmu(-extremes), nsim=100)
```

where Heter is a list (i.e., is.list(Heter) returns TRUE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `capture.output`:

```
capture.output(regtst(regsamlmu(-extremes), nsim=100), file="myoutput.txt")
```

Or for capturing output coming from several consequential commands:

```
sink("myfile.txt")
#
# [commands generating desired output]
#
sink()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a character vector which you write to a file. Each entry in the vector will be separated by a newline character.

```
out <- capture.output(regtst(regsamlmu(-extremes), nsim=100))
write(out, "output.txt", sep="\n")
```

If you would like to add more lines just do something like `c(out, "hello Kostas")`